# Spaces in Python coding style

Tags: python, coding-style, formatting

Python tutorial says "Use spaces around operators and after commas, but not directly inside bracketing constructs: a = f(1, 2) + g(3, 4)." What does "not directly inside bracketing constructs" exactly mean?

Comment: There's examples in [Pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That probably comes from [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  Specifically, see the section on "Whitespace in Expressions and Statements."

From that section:

```
Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations:

- Immediately inside parentheses, brackets or braces.

  Yes: spam(ham[1], {eggs: 2})
  No:  spam( ham[ 1 ], { eggs: 2 } )
```

Answer (score 5):

It means you shouldn't do things like `a = f ( 1 )` or `l = [ 2, 3 ]`.

Answer (score 5):

I think it means do this:

```
x = (1, 2)
```

not this:

```
x = ( 1, 2 )
```