# Python2 having trouble with bit manipulation

Tags: python-2.7, bit-manipulation

```
def countbit(n):
    counter = 0
    while(n):
        counter = counter + n&1
        n = n>>1
    return counter

print (countbit(5))
```

I was trying out a rather simple piece of code which finds the number of unset bits in an integer. I couldn't figure out why this snippet wouldn't work. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Indentation problems?

Comment: [*put spaces around operators except directly inside parentheses*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9714161/995714) to make it more readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) - instead of

```
counter = counter + n&1
```

use

```
counter = counter + (n & 1)
```